# MongoDB considers incorrect type for array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to mongodb and I was playing with mongodb charts. When I have a mixed type arrays `(String, Number)`, it is considering as `(String, String)`. Hence, I am not able to apply numerical aggregation. Below is a sample query,

```
 $project: {
       transposed: {
           $zip: {
                inputs: [[“aaa”,”bbb”], [1, 2]]
            }
       }
  }
```

Is it possible to mention the data type of the elements in the query?

Comment: do you have some sample JSON document? what is the input JSON and what is the output of the query you are expecting. In the MongoDB query, I don't think we can define the data type in the MongoDB query. if we need to model data in the query, you need to use mongoose.

Comment: Thanks @Mallik. I will check mongoose. Btw, you can run this query as it is surrounded by []